# How can I convert a list of multiple rgb values into hex all at once in notepad++?

Tags: hex, notepad++, rgb

As the title states, I have a very large list of at least 20k rgb values, and I want to convert all these values (currently formatted as r, g, b) into hex all at once.

I attempted to use a plugin called "ColorBox", which did work, however for only one rgb value at a time, selecting multiple rgb values presented me with only one hex.

Comment: This site is about programming. Why not to just do a small program to convert them? less then 5 minutes if you know scripting. Else it is just an investment for automation you must do in next days/weeks/years.

Comment: Notepad++ is not the right tool for such job, you'd better to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the RGB values list to demonstrate its format?